# Count elements in lines with awk

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I have a tab-delimited text file containing data like

```
Col 1 Col 2
1     a
1     b
1     c
1     d
1     d
2     a
2     b
3     a
```

so on and so forth.

I would like to transform this structure into

```
  a b c d
1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1
3 1 0 0 0
```

so that, a, b, c and d become columns; 1, 2 and 3 become a single row; and the numbers represent count. E.g. 1 has one "a" and two "d"s.

How can this be accomplished using awk or similar tools?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The formatting here can definitely be confusing if you're new. Check out [this guide](http://superuser.com/editing-help). I fixed it for you this time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>1 {
    count[$1,$2]++;
    rows[$1]++;
    cols[$2]++;
}
END {
    printf("%3s", "");
    for (col in cols) {
        printf("%4s", col);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (row in rows) {
        printf("%3d", row);
        for (col in cols) {
            printf(" %3d", count[row,col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}' data
```

Not necessarily efficient or elegant, but it should be fairly easy to read and gets the job done. Also, the rows are columns will not necessarily be printed in sorted order. The key is the use of `count[row,col]` to simulate a multidimensional array, which is not directly supported in awk. A Google search for "awk multidimensional arrays" will turn up several articles including [this one](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multi_002ddimensional.html#Multi_002ddimensional).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PERL solution:

```perl
  perl -e '
    my (%col1, %col2); 
    while(<>){
        chomp; 
        @a=split(/\s+/); ## split line on whitespace
        $col2{$a[1]}++; ## Collect unique values from the 2nd column
        $col1{$a[0]}{$a[1]}++;## Count values per column/line
    } 
    my @l=sort keys %col2; 
    $"="\t"; ## Array record separator, using tabs to deal with variable size input
    print "\t@l\n"; 
    foreach my $c1 (sort keys(%col1)) {## For each column1 value
        print "$c1\t"; 
        my $str;
        for (my $i=0; $i<=$#l; $i++) {
        ## Collect the values for each position or 0 if there is none
        $col1{$c1}{$l[$i]}="0" unless defined($col1{$c1}{$l[$i]});
        $str.="$col1{$c1}{$l[$i]}\t";
        }
    chop($str); ## remove extra \t 
    print "$str\n";
    }' data   >ll
```